# References for numerical approach of Hilbert uniqueness method (HUM)

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, wave-equation

Finding of the control that achieves the exact controllability of the wave equation (Neumann boundary conditions) using the HUM method (see: J.L. Lions, Controlabilité exacte perturbations et stabilisation des systèmes distribués, Tome 1: controlabilité exacte, Masson, Paris, 1988) depends to the resolution of the equation $\Lambda (\phi_0 , \phi_1 ) = (\psi_t (x,0). \psi(x,0))$.

How can one solve this equation numerically?
How can one find the initial conditions of the adjoint system?